# How to show uploaded images from server(folder) to index page in asp.net webapi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, file-upload

Hi all,

I am working in `asp.net` webapi. I have uploaded my images and I have optimized these images for three different sizes.

Then I clicked on `saved in folder` in `server(App_Data)(folder)` in my application, now I need to

- Retrive those images from that folder
- Show in my index page like i should get that images back
- Show original image
- Show the different images on radio button selection

Could you please help me retrieve those pictures from my folder (show dynamically),and help me fetch and show images in index page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of above i got idea that actually  want to do need to retrive images from folder path right 
ok for that need to write method in controller its just simple

```
public static string Getimage( string url)
          {

              return url;
          }
```

and make call in your controllers like this

```
Getimage(uploadedfolders)
```

uploaded folders means patha of folder which images are stored